# ASP.NET core fails on with

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I try to do a performance test on my asp.net core 1.0.1 website. I use loader.io to get 4000 client's to load the website but I get an error on asp.net core. If I run the same code in asp.net 4.6 it runs error on same server. Can anybody tell my why I can't handle same load on my asp.net core site like my asp.net 4.6?

> Error:
>
> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.

There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

ASP.NET 4.6: https://thusan.tinytake.com/sf/MTA4Mzg1OF80MzMzNzMz

ASP.NET core: https://thusan.tinytake.com/sf/MTA4Mzg1OV80MzMzNzM0

I'm running both sites from IIS on a Windows 2012 r2.

Comment: Have you followed the steps required by typical performance benchmarking? https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks If not, your ASP.NET Core app itself is not yet ready for performance testing.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET 4, IIS hosts the web site in its own process. ASP.NET Core changed this. ASP.NET Core web sites execute as a separate process and IIS uses the ASP.NET Core Module to reverse proxy requests to the ASP.NET Core process. The error you are seeing could be caused by many problems, such as a setup errors or hung requests in the ASP.NET Core process.

If all requests fail, it is probably a setup error. Follow this document to make sure guide you have completed all steps to deploy an ASP.NET Core app to IIS. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html.

If the ASP.NET Core site works for a few requests but fails under stress, checkout some of these recommendations for improving performance. https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/245#issuecomment-242541999